# How to redirect all computers inside company network to one local ip when access mysite.com

Tags: networking, home-networking, hosts

I want to do a redirect like

```
192.169.251.211 mysite.com
```

But i dont want to do this in each host file for all computers inside the company network.

I just want to do this inside the company internet network. What is the ways?

Comment: Does your company have its own DNS server?

Comment: Why not just put it into the DNS?

Comment: You could translate the IP to another with a good router, for example one that has DD-WRT.